# How can rows of a pandas DataFrame all be plotted together as lines?

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

Let's say we have the following DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
         [
             ['Norway'     , 'beta', 30.0 , 31.0, 32.0, 32.4, 32.5, 32.1],
             ['Denmark'    , 'beta', 75.7 , 49.1, 51.0, 52.3, 50.0, 47.9],
             ['Switzerland', 'beta', 46.9 , 44.0, 43.5, 42.3, 41.8, 43.4],
             ['Finland'    , 'beta', 29.00, 29.8, 27.0, 26.0, 25.3, 24.8],
             ['Netherlands', 'beta', 30.2 , 30.1, 28.5, 28.2, 28.0, 28.0],
         ],
         columns = [
             'country',
             'run_type',
             'score A',
             'score B',
             'score C',
             'score D',
             'score E',
             'score F'
         ]
    )
df
```

How could the score values be plotted as lines, where each line corresponds to a country?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you tagged `matplotlib`, here is a solution using `plt.plot()`. The idea is to plot the lines row wise using `iloc`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# define DataFrame here

df1 = df.filter(like='score')

for i in range(len(df1)):
    plt.plot(df1.iloc[i], label=df['country'][i])

plt.legend()  
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try to plot the transpose of the dataframe:

```
# the score columns, modify if needed
score_cols = df.columns[df.columns.str.contains('score')]


df.set_index('country')[score_cols].T.plot()
```

Output:

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: Dammit, if I could select two right answers I would! Thanks for the clean suggestion.